# Azure notification hub, Azure WebApp

Tags: azure, notifications

I am currently working on Azure notification hub, so instead of using a windows app, I want to use azure Web App and push notifications, will that be possible? and also help me with the required links.

Comment: Do you want to push notifications to web apps ? Such as send a notification to web application which accessed in Chrome ?

Comment: yes, please help